# Ubuntu 18.04 clean install with Nvidia NVS 510 drivers only boots every other time

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia

I've now switched off `quite splash` from the boot options so I can see what's going on.

- Clean install of Ubuntu 18.04
- Installed Nvidia NVS 510 drivers `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` -
  got 4 screens working as expected
- LOOP STARTS HERE: I shutdown the machine
- When I reboot I get this as the final set of boot outputs:
  [image: final boot outputs]
- Then the screen loses signal, the num lock light goes off and is unresponsive - dead in the water
- I then hold down the power button to force a shut off of the PC
- Boot again and it boots normally into Ubuntu
- GOTO "LOOP STARTS HERE"

What can I check to help diagnose the problem?

Thanks!

Update:
Output from `sudo fsck -fn /dev/sda2`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Warning!  /dev/sda2 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 3276897 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3277117 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3277119 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3277148 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3277978 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3303203 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305481 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305574 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305812 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305838 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305940 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3305942 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Deleted inode 9175055 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inode 9175069 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 9175080 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 23855381 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -603456 -610368 -(13186883--13186885) -13437120 -13871168 -(95524876--95524877) -(95524894--95524895) -(95553028--95553030) -(95553080--95553081) -(95583162--95583170) -(95587432--95587434) -(95587442--95587444) -(95587448--95587450) -(95587845--95587847) -(95608843--95608845)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (116418453, counted=116410551).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -3276897 -3277117 -3277119 -3277148 -3277978 -3303203 -3305481 -3305574 -3305812 -3305838 -3305940 -3305942 -9175055 -9175069 -9175080 -23855381
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (30247434, counted=30247061).
Fix? no


/dev/sda2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda2: 251382/30498816 files (0.5% non-contiguous), 5546603/121965056 blocks
```

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? What brand SSD/HDD? If SSD, have you checked for a firmware update? Please see my partial answer, below. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I used to have dual-boot but I formatted the drive and it's pure Ubuntu now. It's a Samsung SSD. I haven't checked for firmware updates no... is that likely to cause an issue do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer...

To check your Ubuntu file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

- user ran fsck incorrectly. I advised them.
- user has not checked for Samsung SSD firmware updates. I advised them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my question as I think I had a lot of red herrings and misunderstandings. I followed your instructions, I've updated my question with my new output from `sudo fsck -fn /dev/sda2`.

Comment: @ForceHero you didn't follow my instructions **exactly**. No -fn parameters. Repeat fsck until there are no errors, if possible. Also, did you check for Samsung SSD firmware updates yet?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, I ran your exact command, i.e. with just the -f param when logged in via the bootable USB. I then ran with -fn params once logged in to the Ubuntu install on the SSD. I will check for SSD firmware updates later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ForceHero if you were still getting all of the errors that you show in your updated question, then you still have a very big problem. Never fsck a live mounted system. Try re-doing my answer when booted from a Ubuntu Live USB, and repeat until there are no errors (hopefully). And yes, check that firmware asap.